# CodeIgniter Route Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

Im learning CodeIgniter, thus I am still very new to the platform. I have the following problem:

I created a controller named `admin`;

I then added the path inside the routes file as such:

`$route[admin/dashboard] = 'admin/dashboard`;

**Controller**

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function dashboard($page ='dashboard'){

        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            echo 'error';
            show_404();
        }
        //check if Admin
        $data['isAdmin'] = $this->admin_model->isAdmin($this->session->userID);
        var_dump($data['isAdmin']);
        $data['title'] = $page;
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
```

**routes.php**

```
  #ADMIN

    $route['admin/dashboard'] = 'admin/dashboard'; //ROUTE FOR ADMIN DASHBOARD

    #USERS
    $route['users']= 'users';
    $route['users/index'] = 'users/index';
    $route['users/login'] ='users/login';
    $route['users/dashboard'] ='users/dashboard';
    $route['users/profile'] = 'users/profile';
    $route['users/userpicks/(:any)'] = 'users/userpicks/$1';

    #PAGES
    $route['pages/index'] = 'pages/index';
    $route['pages/user_data_submit'] = 'pages/user_data_submit';
    $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/index/$1';
    $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/index';
```

**Views**

```
admin
 ------- dashboard.php
```

**Config.php**

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite';`

**PROBLEM / QUESTION**

When I try to access `http://mysite/admin/dashboard` I get a 404 error

Tracing the route gives the following problem which I find strange. Looking at the below I believe the problem is with the configuration of `routes.php` ...?

> DEBUG - 2018-06-26 08:53:45 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled DEBUG -
>
> 2018-06-26 08:53:45 --> Client sent : dashboard DEBUG - 2018-06-26
>
> 08:53:45 --> Route found : (:any)  --> pages/index/$1 DEBUG -
>
> 2018-06-26 08:53:45 --> Redirecting to : dashboard  -->
>
> pages/index/dashboard DEBUG - 2018-06-26 08:53:45 --> Global POST, GET
>
> and COOKIE data sanitized DEBUG - 2018-06-26 08:53:45 --> Session:
>
> "sess_save_path" is empty; using "session.save_path" value from
>
> php.ini. ERROR - 2018-06-26 08:53:45 --> 404 Page Not Found:

By looking at the above `http://mysite/admin/dashboard` somehow gets redirected to

> Route found : (:any)  --> pages/index/$1 DEBUG

I find this strange as I have "hardcoded" the route and placed it at the very top of `routes.php` yet it doesn't get executed for some reason...?

Any input and / or help appreciated.

Comment: `http://mysite/index.php/admin/dashboard` ??

Comment: Nope `$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite;`

Comment: no just type that in URL and check page loads

Comment: I just did it gives same result 404

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee: What is your default controller?

Comment: inside dashboard function add `echo 11; die;` and post output

Comment: @Virb it is `$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/index';`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I added your `echo` statment at the very top of the function. Please see update on question, I get the following returned

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee keep same code and  hit this `http://mysite/index.php/admin/dashboard` URL n see

Comment: You advised it earlier -- tried it again same error

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee hey comment this `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/index/$1';`  route

Comment: @AbdullaNilam the strange thing is if I add the `dashboard` function and page inside the `users` directory and add `$route['users/dashboard'] = 'users/dashboard'` it works perfectly. The problem is it doesnt rout to new controller...which is strange...?

Comment: Yes @AbdullaNilam seems to be right the `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/index/$1';` route hits before `$route['admin/dashboard'] = 'admin/dashboard'`

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee check file name correct then. `Admin.php`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam when I comment `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/index/$1'` I get the following error : `Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: core/Router.php`

Comment: The problem might be here `if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){ ... show_404();` it seams that file path is invalid and app can't find the `dashboard.php` view

Comment: make this change in config file : $config['index_page'] = '';  [link](http://mysite/admin/dashboard) ,you will find your page working with this url or else if you are using $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; [link](http://mysite/index.php/admin/dashboard) ,you will find your page working with this url.

Comment: Im giving up and just adding the `Admin` function inside `Users` controller and changing the `$route` accordingly

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity remove routes you define, There is no need to define routes in CI. If you have a controller "admin" and an action dashboard, you can simply browse it with URL

> http://yoursite/admin/dashboard

. If index.php is not removed by you explicitly then URL will be

> http://yoursite/index.php/admin/dashboard

.
If you are on a local machine like XAMP then URL will be

> http://localhost/folderName//index.php/admin/dashboard

.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

**In your route file your should remove**

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
  To 
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**.htaccess File**

And create a .htaccess file on your project root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

this .htaccess file code will remove index.php from url

Comment: My `$config['index_page'] = '';`is already set as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $route['admin'] = "admin/dashboard";

    $route['default_controller'] = "pages/index";
```

(This means the path is controller->pages->index.php) Just confirming it to you.

One more case it might be due to the htacess.php file

Change the route to :

```
http://mysite/index.php/admin/dashboard
```